# How to get range of string in android?

Tags: android, html, string, android-layout, webview

this is my code in xcode:

```
          if ([tempArticles.body rangeOfString:@"[YOUTUBE]"].length>0) {
    [body appendString:[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:
                        @"<div style='margin-top:5px; margin-left:5px; margin-right:5px;margin-bottom;5px;'></div><div  style='font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;fontcolor:gray;'>%1@</div><div><strong style='font-family:Arial; font-size:24; margin-bottom:5;'>%2@</strong></div><div><div style='float: margin-left:2px ;margin-right: 2px;margin-bottom: 1px; margin-top: 25px;'><center><img src='%3@' alt='' style='width:200px; height:127px; margin-bottom:20px;'</center></div><div style='line-height: 20px;font-size:16px; font-family:Arial'>%4@</div></div></div>", completeTanggal, tempArticles.headline, tempArticles.imageURL, bodynew]];
    [self.myWebView loadHTMLString:body baseURL:Nil];
}
else
{
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:tempArticles.body];
    [body appendString:[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:
                        @"<div style='margin-top:5px; margin-left:5px; margin-right:5px;margin-bottom;5px;'></div><div  style='font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;fontcolor:gray;'>%1@</div><div><strong style='font-family:Arial; font-size:24; margin-bottom:5;'>%2@</strong></div><div><div style='float: margin-left:2px ;margin-right: 2px;margin-bottom: 1px; margin-top: 25px;'><center><img src='%3@' alt='' style='width:200px; height:127px; margin-bottom:20px;'</center></div><div style='line-height: 20px;font-size:16px; font-family:Arial'>%4@</div></div></div>", completeTanggal, tempArticles.headline, tempArticles.imageURL, tempArticles.body]];
    NSString *newBody = [body stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"w=150&h=112" withString:@"w=300&h=224"];
    [self.myWebView loadHTMLString:newBody baseURL:baseURL];
    }
 }
```

how i get the code like that in java android ??
thank you

Comment: You want someone to write a bunch of java code for you? How will you be paying - Visa, Mastercard, Paypal...

Comment: no, i just want know how the code in java like "if ([tempArticles.body rangeOfString:@"[YOUTUBE]"].length>0)"

Comment: For java basics check out [Java Language Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html). Your question isn't really a question, but rather asking for someone to teach you java.

Comment: You will have much better luck if you describe in words (not every androider knows ObjC) **1** what do you want **2** what have you tried **3** where exactly do you have problems. Otherwise it looks like you have been lazy to use web search

Comment: Total lack of research from the OP… this is a Java 101 question that Google solves in 10 secs. Possibly duplicate too.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [Java String Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#method_summary). Any decent Objective-C (and most likely C) developer will have an easy time finding a simple method like this in Java. (and the same goes the other way around). Five minutes of Googling and reading the official Java documentation would have solved the problem in less time that it took you to write and copy paste that *relatively horrible* objective-c sample.

<sub>*(Emphasis mine, because that code looks hacky but I have no idea what it really does or why it's there, so I'm just going to pretend it's ok).*</sub>